# What are the redirects between OneLogin OIDC Auth Code Flow parts one and two?

Tags: openid, openid-connect, onelogin

I'm curious what's going on behind the scenes in the OneLogin OIDC login flow. Their support articles mention two parts to the flow:

[`GET` Auth Code Flow pt. 1](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code) - This is where you redirect the browser to the `openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/auth` endpoint to get a onetime code that can be exchanged for a long-term credential.

[`POST`  Auth Code Flow pt. 2](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code-grant) – This is where the user is redirected back to your registered server callback specified in part one and you're supposed to `POST` from your server to finish getting their credentials.

However, in between those two steps, my browser makes a few more stops due to OneLogin giving 302 locations before my specified callback. The final flow looks like this:

1. Hit my server's `/login` endpoint
2. My server issues a 302 redirect to `https://mysubdomain.onelogin.com/oidc/auth?response_type=code&client_id=${client}&redirect_uri=${server}%2Foauth%2Fcallback`
3. OneLogin issues a 302 redirect to `https://mysubdomain.onelogin.com/trust/openid-connect/v2?client_id=${client}&grant=${some uuid}`
4. OneLogin issues a 302 redirect to `https://openid-connect.onelogin.com/oidc/auth/${uuid from step 3}/login?ctw=${a jwt}`
5. OneLogin issues a 302 redirect to `https://mysubdomain.onelogin.com/oidc/auth/${same uuid from step 3}`
6. OneLogin (finally) issues a 302 redirect to `${server}/oauth/callback` with the `?code=` access code I asked for, and an additional `state` query parameter.
7. My server issues a 302 to where the user wanted to go.

What's up with the `mysubdomain` on the OneLogin urls? [OneLogin's docs](https://developers.onelogin.com/openid-connect/api/authorization-code) imply that the target URL for almost every request should be of the form `https://<region>.onelogin.com/oidc/auth?client_id=<client id>&redirect_uri=<redirect uri>&response_type=code&scope=openid` where
`<region>` is explained as

> region **required** string
>
> Set to the region of your OneLogin instance.
>
> - openid-connect
> - openid-connect-eu
>
> e.g. If your OneLogin instance is located in Europe then use `https://openid-connect-eu.onelogin.com/oidc`

If I configure the server to direct the first call (#2 above) to `openid-connect.onelogin.com` instead, the redirect in step 3. goes to `mysubdomain.onelogin.com` before 4. goes back to `openid-connect.onelogin.com`. Convenient that it works either way! But I would like to know what's going on, as I've not found the sub domain identifier mentioned anywhere in the OIDC portion of OneLogin's docs.

Where is the documentation on the `/trust/openid-connect/` and `/oidc/auth/${uuid}` endpoints? (The docs I linked to above for the `/oidc/auth` endpoint make no mention of a uuid path parameter.) Are those just considered implementation details that developers and end users should not be aware of?

What is the uuid that shows up in step 3 and persist through the redirect chain? It's not the clientId and, from what I can tell, it's not anything that makes it back to the final callback in step 6.